# Doubt in definition of congruent modulo

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, modular-arithmetic, definition

My book defines $a\equiv b\pmod n$ as $n|b-a$ where $a, b, n$ are integers.

I want to know that if $a\equiv b\pmod n$ then how is $b$ the remainder of $a$ when divided by $n$ if $b$ is less than $n$?

$a \equiv b\pmod n$ means $n|b-a$ which further implies that $b-a = nq$ for some integer $q$.

Now if $r$ is the remainder when $a$ is divided by $n$. Then there will exist $p$ such that $a = np+r$ which implies $b = a-np$.

From here, how can I conclude that $q = -p$?

Comment: It is not true that $a\equiv b \pmod n$ implies that $b$ is the remainder you get when you divide $a$ by $n$.  $2\equiv 23\pmod 7$ but $23$ is not the remainder you get when you divide $2$ by $7$.

Comment: Which textbook are you referring to?

Comment: The remainder $r$ is the unique number in $[0,n)$ for which $a\equiv r \bmod n$. If there were two distinct such numbers $r_1<r_2$, then $r_1\equiv r_2$ so $n\mid(r_2-r_1)$ but $0<r_2-r_1<n-0$ so cannot be divisible by $n$.

Answer (score 0):

You mention 'there will exist $p$, there will exist $q$', which implies that p and q are not definite numbers, but elements of sets satisfying certain conditions, say $X$ and $Y$.

so you can't get $p=-q$, but $p, -q$ both belong to the same set, i.e. $X=Y$ (which is actually $\mathbb{Z}$).

So basically you mix up equality of sets with equality of numbers.

Comment: Sure, you can't conclude $p=-q$ just from knowing $p$ and $q$ are integers, but OP needs to conclude $p=-q$ from the original hypotheses of the question, namely that $a\equiv b\mod n$ and $b$ is less than $n$ (and OP also forgot to mention $b$ is positive). So this doesn't answer the question (or even attempt to).

Comment: Well, I reread it. Isn't the conclusion of OP obvious? (since a, b are definite)

Comment: @runway44..I edited the question..b is less than n and b is also positive..now how to show that b is the remainder?